# Is it ok/common practice to login via REST service by sending clear text password?

Tags: rest, ssl, authentication, mobile-application

Is it ok/common practice to login via REST service by sending clear text password? As long as it's done over https?
e.g. `https://www.example.com/api/login/<username>/<pwd>`

Or is it common practice to use encryption of the password locally and decryption on the server?

Comment: Never send an unencrypted password regardless of https or not

Comment: URLs can be captured in server logs. More info https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTTP Digest Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) or [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) over HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks! I checked http://dotnetopenauth.net/. There's an oAuth and openId implementation. I don't think openid is relevant to me (I use Facebook and email logins). But oAuth may be. Do you know if I can implement dotnetopenauth to work with my aspnet_membership tables in which I've stored my customers' usernames and passwords?

Comment: @Flo Never used .Net or ASP — sorry!

Answer (score 0):

First of all username along with password should *never* be included in URL. There's `authorization` (with lots of variants - base64, token, whatever) header for such purposes.

Secondly password should be always sent via HTTPS. Or more general, authorization should always be done via HTTPS.

When it comes to encoding password I've worked with system that were sending plain and encrypted passwords. If it's possible to send encrypted, it's much better.